# Logout ? - Parse and Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, logout, parse-platform

Looking at the example at

https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios

I can't make heads or tails of how I logout an enduser.

```
// from the viewcontroller.h file.

// UINavigationBar button touch handler

- (void)logoutButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender;

// And apparently this line ->

(void)logoutButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender { 

// Logout user, this automatically clears the cache [PFUser logOut];

// Return to login view controller.  From the view controller.m file.

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

There's just one little problem with this, how is the logout button is being generated....because its not being generated at all!

Anyone care to illuminate reality for me ????

Thanks.

Miles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pseudo code, a guide, for you to fill in the blanks. In this case the blank is the button itself because the pertinent information for logging out is the `[PFUser logOut];` code, not how you configure your app to call that code.

Comment: Got it all worked out.  It really was a mess!  The solution was in fact to call [PFuser logout] but also needing to call a button action to reference it.